# mysterious Run time error 438 on using web control and html document in vb6

Tags: html, vb6, webbrowser-control

We have a small application written in VB6 that simply reads a web page and displays some data from it in a grid. Until recently everything just worked fine but suddenly some - not all! - of our clients got this error - "run time error 438 object doesn't support this property or method".

As it is quite a large number of people it doesn't seem that they all changed something in their environment (and also because my boss is one of them and he says there was neither change nor update in his computer...) so maybe there was some change in the site? (this is the URL - "http://classic.easy-forex.com/en/Forex.Rates.aspx").

Now, I didn't write this application but I have to fix it. Alas, it works on 2 computers of mine (32 and 64 bit) so I can't even debug it.... I just saw it uses a WebBrowser control which and an HtmlDocument object.

sorry for the length, I am just trying to give all the details. I will be most grateful for any help on this mysterious , for me at least, issue.

many ,many thanks

Comment: To clarify the error the clients got... was this onscreen as part of the rendered code? or a JavaScript error?

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment - I have missed it somehow...it was onscreen (that was err.description)